# C "Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)" when converting int to string

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings

Im currently loosing hope, because I cant find my error. I changed so much in my code, that its terrible now...
To start in the beginning, Im having a linked list:

```
struct list {
int value;
struct list *next;
};
```

For that Im implementing a function, that converts every existing value (so the value of every "next" list) to a concadening string in the form "[value1, value2, ...]". Here is the function:

```
char* cdl_to_string(list_t *list){
int tester = 1;
char* toString =  malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    strcat(toString, "[");
    if(list != NULL){
        while ( tester !=0){
            char *result = malloc(strlen(toString) * sizeof(char ) +1);
            sprintf(result, "%d", list->value);
            strcat(toString,result);
            if(list->next != NULL){
                strcat(toString, ", ");
            }
            else{
                tester = 0;
            }
            list = list->next;
            free(result);
        }
    }
    strcat(toString, "]");
    printf("%s",toString);
    return toString;
    free(toString);
}
```

Im calling the function with this assertion:

```
void givenListWithMultipleElements_toStringIsOk() {
    list_t* head = create_node(INT_MIN);
    list_t* second = create_node(INT_MAX);
    list_t* third = create_node(0);
    head->next = second;
    second->next = third;

    char* result = cdl_to_string(head);

    assert(strcmp("[-2147483648, 2147483647, 0]", result) == 0);
    TEST_SUCCESS("givenListWithMultipleElements_toStringIsOk");

    free(third);
    free(second);
    free(head);
}
```

The weird thing is, that when Im compiling it with Clang in the console or in the IDE it fails with the error from the headline, but in the Intellij debugger it works every other time!?

Im thankfully for every advice!

Edit:
Here hte complete error in the console-compiler:

```
[ OK ]  whenInitList_thenListIsCreated
[ OK ]  givenEmptyList_thenReturnSizeOfZero
[ OK ]  givenListWithOneElement_thenReturnSizeOfOne
[][ OK ]    givenEmptyList_toStringIsOk
zsh: trace trap  ./a.out
```

and here in intellij:

```
[ OK ]  whenInitList_thenListIsCreated
[ OK ]  givenEmptyList_thenReturnSizeOfZero
[ OK ]  givenListWithOneElement_thenReturnSizeOfOne
[][ OK ]    givenEmptyList_toStringIsOk

Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)
```

Comment: You never initialized the contents of `toString`, you can't concatenate to it right after callocating. Use `strcpy()` instead of `strcat()`.

Comment: You only allocated 2 bytes for `toString`, so it only has room for one character and the null terminator. You can't concatenate to it inside the loop unless you increase the allocation with `realloc()`.

Comment: The first two comments already answered the questions, but I also wanted to mention that using a tool like valgrind (or the built in debugger of your IDE) could probably clear up errors like these in the future.

Comment: The allocation for `char *result` is also too short. The size needed has nothing to do with `toString`, but the maximum length of an `int` as a string. You don't even need dynamic allocation for that: a local `char result[16]` will do.

Comment: Calling [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) with a buffer size of zero will tell you the length of the string that *would* have been produced. You can use this to total up the length of the complete string, by iterating the list once beforehand, and then use that length to perform a single allocation. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/bPGhcYsM8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***"Do not lose hope, nor be sad."***

The statement:

```
char* toString =  malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
```

allocates memory for 2 bytes, including the null-terminator.

Then, the call to `strcat()`:

```
strcat(toString, "[");
```

tries to concatenate a string to uninitialized memory. If we were to look at the man page:

> The strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string,
> overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest,
> and then adds a terminating null byte.  The strings may not
> overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the
> result.  If dest is not large enough, program behavior is
> unpredictable; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for
> attacking secure programs

We see that `strcat()` must first find the null byte that terminates the string using a search that starts at the beginning of the string, but you never initialised the contents of `toString`, so this invokes undefined behaviour.

The call to `strlen()` then, is unlikely to succeed:

```
char *result = malloc(strlen(toString) * sizeof(char ) +1);
```

If `toString` was properly null-terminated, this too would allocate merely 2 bytes for `result`, which might not (and it surely doesn't seem to) be able to represent the value of `list->value`.

The subsequent calls to `strcat()` have the same problem.

Aside: Do not discard the result of `mallloc()`.